# Paginator setting prevPage and nextPage parameter in view as 1 for all pages

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.4

When paginating results in CakePHP 2.4.2 the `$this->params['paging']['Post']['nextPage']` parameter in the view is always 1 for all pages. So is the `prevPage` parameter.

Here is how the `paging` data looks like on page 2

```
        [paging] => Array
            (
                [Post] => Array
                    (
                        [page] => 2
                        [current] => 40
                        [count] => 1719
                        [prevPage] => 1
                        [nextPage] => 1
                        [pageCount] => 43
                        [order] => Array
                            (
                                [Post.created] => DESC
                            )

                        [limit] => 40
                        [options] => Array
                            (
                                [page] => 2
                            )

                        [paramType] => named
                    )

            )
```

Here is my `$this->paginate` settings in the controller.

```
Array
(
[conditions] => Array
    (
        [Post.published] => 1
    )

[contain] => Array
    (
        [Feed] => Array
            (
                [fields] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => id
                        [1] => board_id
                    )

                [Board] => Array
                    (
                        [fields] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => id
                                [1] => title
                                [2] => key
                            )

                    )

            )

        [PostFeature] => Array
            (
                [fields] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => id
                        [1] => width
                        [2] => height
                        [3] => url
                        [4] => color
                    )

            )

    )

[fields] => Array
    (
        [0] => id
        [1] => feed_id
        [2] => post_feature_id
        [3] => title
        [4] => summary
        [5] => author
        [6] => url
        [7] => score
        [8] => published_when
        [9] => board_count
        [10] => like_count
        [11] => liked
        [12] => tagged
    )

[order] => Array
    (
        [Post.created] => DESC
    )

[limit] => 40
[maxLimit] => 40
)
```

I can't figure out why paginator is not sending the correct prev/next page numbers to the view?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me.

These parameters are not page numbers. They are boolean values if a next or prev page exists in the set. So the values are correct.

I'll leave this here to save other people the embarrassment.